# How can I get a picture of an HTML element's content, including content not visible on the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html2canvas, drawimage

What I want to do is take a screenshot using html2canvas.js library but of the whole div not part of it which is only included in the client's view.

What happens with my way of doing it is that it crops me only a part of the div, which is being visibile in the client. For example this [Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLon9.png) out of this [Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He15l.png).
It cuts it based on the view from the browser.

I reasearched and found out that Element.scrollWidth might solve the issue, but it does the same job as trying with Element.clientWidth or with HTMLElement.offsetWidth.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Ho8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Was using bad version of html canvas, 1.4.0 worked fine and solved my problem
https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas
https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js